# SET a property during a custom cypher query

Tags: neo4j, graphql, cypher, grandstack

Is something like this advisable?

```
GetConversationsByMember(userId: ID!): [Conversation]
    @cypher(
        statement: """
            MATCH (u:User {id: $userId})-[:IN_CONVERSATION]->(c:Conversation)-[:NEWEST_MESSAGE]->(newestMessage)
            SET c.hasReadNewest = EXISTS((u)-[:HAS_READ]->(newestMessage))
            RETURN c
    """)
```

I have the `hasReadNewest` property on the `Conversation` node and I want to dynamically set it when getting all conversations for a user. Right now I'm running into this error `Neo4jError: Set property for property 'hasReadNewest' is not allowed for user 'neo4j' with roles [PUBLIC, admin] restricted to READ.` and questioning this approach altogether.

Comment: Probably you should use a mutation instead of a query when doing updates to the database

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick.